# Load a png file from a compilabe C source code

Tags: png, embedded-resource, gtk2

I converted a png -> c, with png2c. And I can compiled the source code with my code without a problem. My question is how can I access that part of the code in the my gtk_image_new_from_pixbuf? Anyone have stories about the subject?

/Edit: Here is the header code:

`````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````
/*  GIMP header image file format (RGB): /icon.h  */

static unsigned int width = 255;
static unsigned int height = 255;

/*  Call this macro repeatedly.  After each use, the pixel data can be extracted  */

#define HEADER_PIXEL(data,pixel) {\
pixel[0] = (((data[0] - 33) << 2) | ((data[1] - 33) >> 4)); \
pixel[1] = ((((data[1] - 33) & 0xF) << 4) | ((data[2] - 33) >> 2)); \
pixel[2] = ((((data[2] - 33) & 0x3) << 6) | ((data[3] - 33))); \
data += 4; \
}
static char *header_data =
    "````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````"
    "````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````"
    "````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````"
// more code
`````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````

Comment: It's not code, it is data. Do you get any output file at all from this tool?

Comment: I use gimp to convert the png to h, so can be easly included. Yeah, I got a header file.